# Users Migration to SkypeForBusiness Cloud with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business

I am trying to find Skype For Business module for PowerShell in order to manage our SFB users.

At the moment our environment is hybrid and I need to migrate all on-prem users to the cloud. Can you please suggest a module I should read about?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you anything tried on your own so far?

Comment: Yes mate! I've tried looking for modules but non of the TechNet pages I've read did not help me! Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can try the following links:

1. It contains the module required for Skype For Business

[Manage Skype for Business Online with Office 365 PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/manage-skype-for-business-online-with-office-365-powershell)

2. Explains how you can move Users between On-Premises and Cloud

[Move users between on-premises and cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/hybrid/move-users-between-on-premises-and-cloud)

Hope these information will help you.